# When providing a Spring RestController as a part of a library, how should I make dependencies be injected?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I'm providing a Spring RestController as a part of a library. Currently I have reusable jaxrs services, but I need to make Spring Boot alternatives. One RestController for example has 2 dependencies: one is a service that I could see being a bean and the other a String property.

I'm wondering what is the idiomatic way to expect to get those dependencies from users consuming the library. I had a few ideas about how it might happen, but wasn't sure what was the right or at least best practice way to do it.

1. Should users construct the RestController manually using the constructor (not using dependency injection)? I actually couldn't even figure out how to do this such that the Spring Boot Application knew about it and didn't see it in guides, so I was assuming this isn't the normal way to provide RestControllers. I only wondered if this was the right way to go as dependency injection being used for a third party library class's dependencies seems like it could be hard to manage.
2. Should both be beans, with the String property being a named bean? I have this one working, but I'm wondering if consumers of the library having to provide beans that the library's RestController expects is tricky or a bad practice.
3. Should the simple service be a bean and the String injected via @Value?
4. Is there some alternative or better way?

Comment: Would you expect the application to crash if the beans required by your `@RestController` within the library wouldn't be provided by the consumers of your library?